# What does "run them off their feet" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, definition

Two black guys go to Ohio State University in 1933. White dudes lock horns with them. One black guy asks another what are they supposed to do, if not kicking their ass. There is the answer: "You just smile and play nice. **Run every last one of these peckerwoods off their feet**."
I'm not sure what does the lat line mean.

Comment: Peckerwoods or woodpeckers?

Comment: It's official subs, so it's peckerwoods. Anyway I don't understand exactly "run off their feet" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run someone off their feet means, usually, to make someone work very hard.
Peckerwoods is southern (US) slang for redneck or poor white person. Two examples I have made up:

- My boss was in a really bad mood today and ran us off our feet.
- I've had so much to do today and my kids have  really run me off my feet.

Comment: Yes, I found this defenition, but it makes a little sense to me in this context. Thanks anyway

Comment: I imagine this story involves Jesse Owens, who matriculated at OSU in 1933, or his teammates on the OSU track team. If that's the case, "run" would have a literal sense, too: the speaker advises his friend to exhaust their white competitors by outperforming them in speed and endurance.

Comment: Yes, that's the story. It confused me because Jesse and his fried were actually runners. Thanks a lot

Comment: As a speaker of US English, I have never heard it used to mean "make someone work very hard"; that appears to be mainly a British expression.  Given that the speakers were all American, I think a more literal interpretation is in order.

Comment: I was run off my feet [at work. by the kids.by the dog] etc. etc. is not a BrE expression. If the people were runners, then, it's funny and just means to run a whole lot (to use an AmE expression).

Comment: [Yes, "run/rushed off my feet" is absolutely more a BrE expression than an AmE one.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=run+off+my+feet%3Aeng_us_2012%2Crun+off+my+feet%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Crushed+off+my+feet%3Aeng_us_2012%2Crushed+off+my+feet%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crun%20off%20my%20feet%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crun%20off%20my%20feet%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crushed%20off%20my%20feet%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crushed%20off%20my%20feet%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @stangdon  No, it isn't more British. To be run ragged, to be run off one's feet. google the word books + "run off her feet", many hits, not at all, all British English. Look at Fired Up (Trouble in Texas) "Glynna had been run off her feet and hadn't eaten since before sunrise". Very run-of-the-mill, in fact....